# Converting an existing image(8 bit, 32 bit etc) to 24 bit png in php

Tags: php, imagemagick, png

How can I convert existing png images to 24 bit png image.

The existing images may be with 8 bit, 16 bit, 32 bit, 48 bit or 64 bit. I want to convert them all in 24 bit png images.

I tried imagemagick on my localhost (Window 7) using php
followings are command I tried.

```
shell_exec('C:\\imagemagick\\convert -depth 24 sentences.png sentences2.png');
```

or

```
shell_exec('C:\\imagemagick\\convert sentences.png -transparent white png24:sentences2.png');
```

None of the above worked correctly for me. The above scripts are converting images in random bit depth. For example if sentences.png is of 8 bit depth, after converting it becomes 32 bit. Similarly for other images, it becomes 32 bit, some times 48 bit etc.

How to correctly achieve this conversion from any png to 24bit png?

Comment: "-depth 24" means 24 bits per color sample, 96 bits total (3 bytes each of red, green, blue, and alpha).  You want "-depth 8".  But PNG24 does mean 24-bit pixels, 1 byte each of red, green, and blue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Imagick PHP functions like so:

```
$imagick_image = new Imagick($image_filename);
$imagick_image->writeImage("png24:$image_filename");
```

Comment: I tried to install Imagick on my localhost/wamp but could not, as i dont know which version of imagick .dll file is compatible with my wamp. The php version is 5.5.12.

Comment: This is a really good tutorial on how to set it up: http://www.elxsy.com/2009/07/installing-imagemagick-on-windows-and-using-with-php-imagick/
EDIT: For downloading php_imagick.dll you can get it from here: http://pecl.php.net/package/imagick